# Finding words with same first bits of their sha1 hash

Tags: python, sha1

I need to find 2 words whose hashes match in the first couple of bits.

I've already tried doing this by taking a random number and then checking if any of the numbers in a certain range have the same first 11 hex characters, but this returns no results.

```py
import random
import hashlib 
for y in range (0,20):
    a = random.randint(0,6000000)
    stra = str(a)
    result = hashlib.sha1(stra.encode()) 
    print(result.hexdigest()) 
    print(a)
    re = result.hexdigest()
    for i in range(0, 6000000):
            secon = str(i)
            seconda = hashlib.sha1(secon.encode())
            second = seconda.hexdigest()
            if re[0:10] == second[0:10]:
                if re != second:
                    print("dwkdowkd")
                    print(re)
                    print(second)
```

Comment: FYI, `[0:10]` is the first 10 characters, not 11.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, which makes the problem even worse.

Comment: I suggest you create a list of the first 10 characters of all the hashes, then use `collection.counter()` to see how many duplicates there are. Probably not many.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.   
*Why* does this not return any results?  Did you get any qualifying hash pairs?  What did you do to test that matching pairs *would* get properly identified?  You didn't post your attempts to demonstrate the failure or otherwise trace the problem; this code contains random (i.e. mystery) values and no output.  If nothing else, a few strategic `print` commands would do wonders for the posting.

Comment: I've tried certain words in ranges that I know contain collision words and it prints out the pairs correctly, so if there is a word with a matching hash in the range it'll find it. That part works correctly. What I'm wondering is how I can find these collisions more efficiently, since random numbers clearly very rarely have a collision of any kind.

Comment: Did you try the method suggested by @Barmar. It gave me couple of pairs where the 10 chars matched

Comment: @Nithin would you mind sharing some of the code? I'm fairly new to python so I'm struggling with adding to the list and using counter to find duplicates.

Comment: You are basically checking whether 40 random bits have a specific value, which has a probability of 2<sup>-40</sup> - about one in a trillion.  A mere 6 million attempts is *nowhere near* enough to make this likely.  Now, if you were checking for collisions with *all* of the previously-generated hashes, rather than just one of them, that makes things much more likely (due to the "birthday paradox") - 6 million attempts would almost certainly succeed.